# Why this JQuery condition doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code doesnt correctly works. It must be the search input that will be appear at click event on search-btn.. When it will be (i didnt show this in the snippet below) appear, the submit btn will take frontface place as clickbtn to find smth.. search-btn (the search-btn for show/hide input and submit-to -search btn are similar, but there are 2 of them) will hide with z-index property. And i also unsuccessfully try to make event listener to track any click where event.target will not be a search-btn(or submit-btn, or input).

The code of js file is:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e){
    if (!$('[name="searchFor"]').hasClass('search-anim') && event.target === $('img')){
        $('[name="searchFor"]').addClass('search-anim');
        searchFor.style.visibility = 'visible';
        searchFor.focus();
        submitBtn.style.display = 'block';
        console.log("Yes");
    }  else {
        console.log(e.target);

    }
```

The html is:

```
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-box">    
                <a href="" class="logo">
                    <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <nav>
                    <div><a href="">Home</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Portfolio</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Blog</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Pages</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Features</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Mega Menu</a></div>
                    <div><a href="">Contact</a></div>
                </nav>
                <div class="search">
                    <div class="search-block">
                        <button type="image" name="submitSearchIco" class="clickable"> 
                            <img src="./img/icon-find.png" alt="Search">
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submitSearch" for="searchFor"> 
                            <img src="./img/icon-find.png" alt="Search">
                        </button>
                        <input type="text" name="searchFor" id="search-inp">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </header>
```

The SCSS is:

```
           .search{
                display: flex;
                align-self: center;
                justify-content: center;
                align-content: center;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
                div{
                    [name="searchFor"]{
                        position: relative;
                        width: auto;
                        align-self: center;
                        outline: none;  
                        border: 1px solid transparent;
                        margin: auto 0;
                        padding: .5rem 3rem .5rem 1.5rem;
                        transition: border 1.5s, border-radius .5s, 
                        visibility 1s linear;
                    }
                    .search-anim{
                        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
                        border-radius: 1.5rem;
                    }
                    [type="submit"], [type="image"]{
                        outline: none;
                        border: none;
                        background: transparent;
                        margin: auto 10px;
                        padding: 0;
                        position: absolute;
                        right: 5px;
                        top: 3px;
                        bottom: 0;

                    }
                    [type="submit"]{
                        z-index: 5;

                    }
                    [type="image"]{
                        z-index: 3;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `event.target === $('img')` is never going to be true. Was the intent here something like `$(event.target).is('img')`? You can do that with jQuery’s built-in event delegation anyway.

Comment: Please post minimal code samples. (e.g. why do we need all your SCSS?)

Comment: Side note - if you're loading in jQuery at all why not adhere to its structure instead of mixing in raw js with jquery? ex: `document.body.addEventListener('click',` - why not `$('body').on('click',...`

Comment: Why do people mix and match vanilla javascript and jquery?  If you're going to use jquery, then use it:  `$(document).on("click", "img", function() { ...`

Comment: Where did the `event` in your if statement come from? Shouldn't this be `e` from the `addEventListener`-method?

Comment: @RMo It can be one of that both

Comment: Thanks to you all, especially @Ryan

Comment: and @KaiQing also

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function (e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName + " clicked!");
});

$("[name='searchFor']").on("click", function() {
//Do your thang
});
```

Your code seems pretty overcomplicated. Try to seperate it out into smaller helpful jobs.

First above is for analytics.
Second is for you to do your show/hide and logging on click of the input.